# Set all values to zero except one in a single row

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I've two tables (both with the same structure) with eleven fields each one (ID and ten more) in which I need to update all the values to zero for a specific ID. Obviously all but the ID.

```
+-----+------+------+------+-...-+-------+
| ID  | val1 | val2 | val3 |     | val10 |
+-----+------+------+------+-...-+-------+
| 45  | 25   |  87  | 310  |     |   12  | 
+-----+------+------+----- +-...-+-------+
```

Does exist any simpler way to do it more than write all the fields equal to zero?

(Note: I don't know if it matters but I'm working with a stored procedure).

Thanks so much.

Comment: You have to mention the columns being updated, but if the names are similar as in your example, you can construct them through a loop!

Comment: @Nadeem_MK No, they're not similar. It was just an example.

Answer (score 0):

According to mySql syntax, you should mention the column names in an Update query (as per [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html)).

However, if you specify the values in the same order as the table definition you could use ***(which is not recommended)***;

```
REPLACE INTO table VALUES(45, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

But note that this will replace the entire row, so you must specify all the values you need, including the ID!

Comment: Why do you say it's not recommended?? It's because of the ID or ...¿?

Comment: yes right, because there's no `where` statement and the `ID` also is being updated, even though you can replace it by the same value!